# How to fetch the data from Odata query by column name in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm, odata

Using the OData.Feed() I am trying to fetch the data from the dynamics. database_url?$select=* giving the all columns data where as when I am trying to fetch the data by column name then it's missing the some columns.

For example,

1. database_url?$select=* giving the result column:- A , B, C, D, E, F, G, H
2. database_url?$select=A , B, C, D, E, F, G, H  giving the result column:- A , B, G, H

when trying to fetch the data using the missing column database_url?$select=C, D, E, F then it's giving the result same as select=*.
Please suggest the solution to get the correct result using the 2 option.

Thanks

Comment: you are probably passing the wrong column names in the select query.

Comment: @JoaoLeal I cross check the column more than 5 times, even I copy the column name which I get from database_url?$select=* and pass that values in query that's also not giving the values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community It's business sensitive. That's why it's secure from outside no one can able to access it. I have shared the example for that, If need more information to understand the error I will share that but can't able to share the ODATA  url.